# How to check request come from internal server

Tags: php, apache

i made a project that can only restrict request from internal server (on those machine).

is there any way to check the request come from internal server using php?

something like cron job that can only executed if requested from internal server. if any request from external site, than ignore it.

Comment: im guessing you don't want to just restrict the IP that connects?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "internal server"?

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this on this way

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1')
 die('Only internal requests are allowed');
```

Comment: i try to debug request. and server remote address don't return 127.0.0.1